# How to get the offset position of a div - cross-browser issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a markup like this

```
<div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>World</div>
</div>
```

I am using first div as float right and second one as float left.

The problem is to get the position of the end corner of "World" div

I used the JS like this

```
var left = $('.inner-page-right-content').offset().left;
left = -(900- left);
$('#inner-page-container').css('background-position',left);
```

The code works in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox 
where it is showing the real distance from window (without float).

Any help or insight will be really appreciated 
[image]

Comment: Why are you floating one div to the left and the other one to the right? I would float both of them left and define a margin for the first one. Then all values will be fixed and there is no need to calculate the position.

Comment: or/and you can give the width in % if you like to float left and right.
i think this is creating issue :left = -(900- left);

Comment: I found [this seemingly duplicate jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7885), but it was for jQuery 1.4.4 (looks like it was fixed in 1.6?) and is a 3-year old bug. What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This throws the same result in Chrome and Firefox

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <style type="text/css"> 
         #hello {
            float: right;
            width: 100px;
            background: grey;
            color: white;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #world {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            background: grey;
            color: white;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #result {
            clear: both;
        }

        </style>  

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var oWorld = $("#world").get(0);
                var rect = oWorld.getBoundingClientRect();

                $("#result").html("top: "+rect.top+", Right: "+rect.right);
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="hello">hello</div>
            <div id="world">World</div>
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>     
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `getBoundingClientRect()`

```
// Assuming your 'world' div has an id="world"
var rect = document.getElementBydId('world').getBoundingClientRect();

rect.left // x position of #world relative to viewport
rect.top // y position of #world relative to viewport
rect.width // width of #world, including padding and borders
rect.height // height of #world, including padding and borders
rect.offsetWidth // width of #world - IE8 and below
rect.offsetHeight // height of #world - IE8 and below
```

## Important notes

- left and top positions are relative to viewport, meaning that
  scrolling is NOT taken into account. Add scroll x and y values to get
  real absolute position.
- CSS transforms are taken into account.

[See the doc on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 1):

Try

`dom.getBoundingClientRect()`

You can use this method get a dom's rectangle. It containes left top bottom right position
relative to the browser.